# Why does the Entity Comparison module throw this exception with Webform submissions?

Tags: entities, webforms, 10

I am using Drupal 10 with the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and the [Entity Comparison](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_comparison) modules.

The goal of the website is allowing users to submit a product as a webform. Later, users should be able to select 2 submissions and compare the entities. This is where I am stuck: The *Entity Comparison* module gives me an error when I add the webform entity I created.

This is the error that I can see in the logs:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "entity.entity_view_display.webform_submission.view_mode" does not exist." at /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 206, referer: http://localhost:8080/admin/structure/entity_comparison/add

Does anyone know how to fix this, or another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What if you implement a custom entity and create it on the webform submission? Could it help?

Comment: If you get an error it is critical that you include the error text in the Question, or this is unanswerable. Also, there should be only one question in the Question.

Comment: @cilefen I edited the post to include the error and remove the second question.